# Deploying a runnable jar in ECLIPSE by considering dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, dependencies, runnable

I have a problem with deploying a JAVA project into a runnable jar file. My project consists of two classes, namely “JFrame” and “Sudoku”. The “JFrame” is a GUI which has a button invoking the main method of the class “Sudoku”. Also, the project must link to an external library including “com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.jar” and “jniconstraintsolver.dll”. When I push the button of the GUI within ECLIPSE environment, it returns the solution in the GUI textbox and everything is nice and OK. However, when I am deploying it into a runnable jar and then clicking on the GUI and then pushing the button, nothing happens!!
Thanks everyone for help, in advance. Consider that I am a beginner in JAVA.

Comment: Consider deploying with java Webstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a piece of cake for my case. I simply put .dll file next to .jar file and Bingo!! I found that it checks the working dir each time executing the .jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you extract all your project dependencies when you build runnable jar.
If you do it in Eclipse, then r.click the project root->export->runnable jar (check the correct option for the dependencies extraction).

[image]

If you package the jar from command line, check the jar comand manual for including runtime dependencies.

Good Luck!

Comment: do you see them when you open the jar?

Comment: To your surprised, yes.

Comment: well... "To my surprised" indeed. Something is different when you run it outside of Eclipse. Do you have application logging?

Comment: I you mean "logging application exceptions", NO.

Comment: I mean log files where you can check if anything goes wrong. If you don't have them, you are on your own, sorry.

Comment: Please see link below. This is my original project plus runnable jar file. http://www.mediafire.com/?a6gda11bdc7svt7